# Using gradle, exclude junit test except when doing distribution task

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, gradle, categories

I have some slow jUnit tests that I typically skip during a build using a SlowTests category, e.g.

#### myjava.java

```
package com.mycompany.package;

public interface SlowTests { }

public class MyTests {
  @Category(SlowTests.class)
  @Test
  public final void testSomethingTakingALongTime() {
    // Some test that takes a while (say over 10 seconds) to run.
  }
}
```

#### build.gradle

```
// Gradle stuff...

test {
    useJUnit {
        excludeCategories 'com.mycompany.package.SlowTests'
    }
}

// More gradle stuff...
```

However, I would like to include these slow running tests before doing a the `publish` task.

Any ideas on how I might be able to achieve this?

Would just adding a second task that `publish` depends on be the easiest solution?